# How to find all projects where client & user involved in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At first, I want to show my associated models as like

```
#=> client.rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :client_assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :client_assignments
end

#=> client_assignment.rb
class ClientAssignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :client
end

#=> project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :client_assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :clients, through: :client_assignments
    validates :client_assignments, presence: true

    has_many :user_assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :user_assignments
    validates :user_assignments, presence: true
end

#=> user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :user_assignments
end

#=> user_assignment.rb
class UserAssignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The concept is "A project involved with a `client` & `current_user`".

I'm struggling for that how to find `current_user` involved projects where `client` is specific, **For example:** I have a `client_id` & which is `2` so how I find all projects for this client where matching `current_user.id`.

I don't know how I describe this.

Please let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I feel like something like this should work:

```
current_user.projects.joins(:clients).where('clients.id = ?', client_id)
```

you want all the projects associated w/ the current user and then find all the clients associated w/ those projects and filter by the specific client_id.

This should do the same thing and may be faster because it avoids a join:

```
current_user.projects.joins(:client_assignments).where(clients_id:client_id)
```